# How can i view white wire in sculpt mode?

Tags: 3d-view, sculpting

I'm beginner in English and blender3d.

When i study sculpting of blender in youtube, there are white wires only in front-face of object in streamer's viewport like below picture.

[image]

But when i select wireframe of viewport shading in sculpt mode, there are orange wires besides back- face wires shown annoyed me like below picture.

[image]

How can I let view port shading be seen like youtube streamer?

Comment: you have to seek the theme he is using dude

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two things to do.

1. For the wireframe color, go to ***User Preferences > Themes > 3D View > Active Object*** colour.
2. In the "N" (shortcut) panel turn on **Backface Culling** under **Shading** tab to hide back part of your mesh.

[image: final]